# Openresty: create connection to Tarantool on init

Tags: lua, openresty, tarantool

I want to create connection to Tarantool database in `init_by_lua_block` or `init_worker_by_lua_block` and then use that created connection in each `content_by_lua_block`:

```
init_by_lua_block {
    local tnt = require 'resty.tarantool'

    local tar, err = tnt:new({
        host = '127.0.0.1',
        port = 3312,
        user = 'user',
        password = 'password',
        socket_timeout = 2000
    })

    local res, err = tar:connect()
}
```

But cosocket api is disabled in directives `init_*_by_lua*`. How I can create connection one time instead of creating connections for each request?

Answer (score 0):

Use https://github.com/perusio/lua-resty-tarantool#set_keepalive

> Makes the connection created get pushed to a connection pool so that the connection is kept alive across multiple requests.

Comment: You cannot use tcp in `init_by_lua_block`